# Why is $P(-1.33<z<1.33) = 1 - 2P(z<-1.33)$

Tags: statistics

[image]

Does anyone know what happens here? I think I am missing some rule or something because I have no clue.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this picture, $P(-1.33 < x < 1.33)$ is the white area (under the curve), $P(x < -1.33)$ is the red area, and $P(x > 1.33)$ is the blue area.

Since the area from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ is $1$ by definition, then the red area + blue area + white area is $1$, and the white area = $1$ - red area - blue area. Additionally, since the normal distribution is symmetric, then the red area = blue area.

Can you convert this back into mathematical notation?

Answer (score 2):

If $P(X)$ is a symmetric PDF then

$$P(z < -x) = P(z > x)$$
$$P(-x < z < x) = 1 - P(z < -x) - P(z > x)$$
$$P(-x < z < x) = 1 - 2 \cdot P(z < -x)$$